# How to use Maptiler to display tiles in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maptiler

I have an image 1810x14871  png file, and I would like to display it as tiles on Google maps.

I'm using Maptiler, I would like to check with you few points:

1) Since I would like to display it on Google maps. Hence, in first screen I have to select "Mercator tiles", right?

2) In the coordinate System screen, my image is based on WGS84 projection. Hence, Do I need to select WGs84, or  "Web Mercator", or UTM Projected?

3) In Geographical Location page, I selected "Load from World file", I created a .wld file with the following content:
0.2751031636863824
0.00000
0.00000
-0.26898567682063484
611289.7255515818
2614249.2935071616

Is it OK? please advice if I made a mistake somewhere, because tiles is not displayed on Google maps.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) yes, choose mercator tiles

2) WGS84 is default, so just click on set in the coordinate system box

3) There is a specification from ESRI how to save a worldfile: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?pid=3034&topicname=World_files_for_raster_datasets

In your case I would maybe try visual georeferencing - will be quicker, here is how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJxdCe9CNYg