# Creating world file for maptiler

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-projections, wgs84, maptiler

I have an image which 21810x14872 that project a box of an area with coordinate:

top, left corner latitude longitude : 23.635069763547662 ,    58.09107365049769
bottom, right corner latitude longitude : 23.598520470202025      , 58.14957297881731

OR using WGS84 northing, easting:

top, left corner easting, northing :      617289.588, 2610249.342
bottom, right corner easting, northing :  611289.588, 2614249.428

My image use projection of  WGS84. How do I create world file for maptiler using above description.

Thanking You.

Comment: already replied in your another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528809/how-to-use-maptiler-to-display-tiles-in-google-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.com/) you can use the "Bounding Box" georeferencing - to provide the four limiting coordinates (north, south, east, west) you mentioned above to assign location to your image directly. You probably don't need to create a World file then.

Just choose in MapTiler the "Mercator tiles", then drag&drop in your file, select your coordinate system (default is the WGS84 geodetic latitude / longitude) and on assign location click on Bounding box. A dialog opens when you can directly type the four numbers. MapTiler previews the covered area in the small map window in bottom right corner.

See these video tutorials which demonstrate the usage of Bounding Box:

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8rNkaNXDPs&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PiQd1mO-S9QrCjqSn1v-ay

and another which also generates MBTiles and upload these to Amazon S3:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf8itiTwo6w&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PiQd1mO-S9QrCjqSn1v-ay

BTW WGS84 is a world *geodetic* system (latitude and longitude) in degrees. It is not a map projection nor projected system. The second coordinates you mentioned look like UTM coordinates or another projected coordinates in meters. To use these you would need to know the exact coordinate system definition (ideally so called EPSG code - see our http://epsg.io/).