# Selecting Coordinate System in Maptiler

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-projections, wgs84, maptiler

I have an image which 21810x14872 that project a box of an area with coordinate:

top, left corner latitude longitude : 23.635069763547662 , 58.09107365049769 bottom, right corner latitude longitude : 23.598520470202025 , 58.14957297881731

OR using WGS84 northing, easting:

top, left corner easting, northing : 617289.588, 2610249.342 bottom, right corner easting, northing : 611289.588, 2614249.428

My image use projection of WGS84. I'm not sure which Coordinate System in Maptiler I need to select? Please advice.

Thanking You.

Comment: already replied here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26528809/how-to-use-maptiler-to-display-tiles-in-google-maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is equal to: [Creating world file for maptiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535911/creating-world-file-for-maptiler)

In MapTiler (http://www.maptiler.com/) you can use the "Bounding Box" georeferencing - to provide the four limiting coordinates (north, south, east, west) you mentioned above to assign location to your image directly. You probably don't need to create a World file then.

Just choose in MapTiler the "Mercator tiles", then drag&drop in your file, select your coordinate system (default is the WGS84 geodetic latitude / longitude) and on assign location click on Bounding box. A dialog opens when you can directly type the four numbers. MapTiler previews the covered area in the small map window in bottom right corner.

See these video tutorials which demonstrate the usage of Bounding Box:

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8rNkaNXDPs&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PiQd1mO-S9QrCjqSn1v-ay

and another which also generates MBTiles and upload these to Amazon S3:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf8itiTwo6w&list=PLGHe6Moaz52PiQd1mO-S9QrCjqSn1v-ay

BTW WGS84 is a world *geodetic* system (latitude and longitude) in degrees. It is not a map projection nor projected system. The second coordinates you mentioned look like UTM coordinates or another projected coordinates in meters. To use these you would need to know the exact coordinate system definition (ideally so called EPSG code - see our http://epsg.io/).

Comment: Thanks @Klokan Technologies ... I'm not sure what 4 numbers I need to write on the Bounding box? Are those latitude & longitude? or northing easting?

Comment: The dialog MapTiler asks for Bounding Box for "west south east north" (minx miny maxx maxy) so for your numbers it means probably:

23.598520470202025 58.09107365049769 23.635069763547662 58.14957297881731

If you select in the first step coordinate system WGS84 (latitude & longitude).